# view registers in gdb not change after flow program c

Tags: c, gdb, cpu-registers

I'm studying the architecture of C programs through gdb software. I made the following program to check the operation of the stack.

I using the code bellow.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void foo(double x, double y)
{
        double a=255;
        double b=255;
        double c=255;
        double d=255;
        double e=255;
        double f=255;
        double g=255;
        double h=255;
        double i=255;
        double j=255;
        double k=255;
        double l=255;
        double m=255;
        double o=255;
        double p=255;

        double a1=255;
        double b1=255;
        double c1=255;
        double d1=255;
        double e1=255;
        double f1=255;
        double g1=255;
        double h1=255;
        double i1=255;
        double j1=255;


        double a2=255;
        double b2=255;
        double c2=255;
        double d2=255;
        double e2=255;
        double f2=255;
        double g2=255;
        double h2=255;
        double i2=255;
        double j2=255;


        c=a+b;
}

double main()
{
        foo(255,255);
        return 0;
}
```

compile the program

```
gcc -g -o exemplo01 exemplo01.c
```

I made a breakpoint in the main function and run the program in gdb,  and I was executing the 'step' command and viewing the contents of the SP register, but it does not change the value. As I'm creating variables in the foo function, should not it stack up?

```
ricardobarbosa@isadora:~/dev/c/pilha$ gdb exemplo01
GNU gdb (Ubuntu 7.7.1-0ubuntu5~14.04.2) 7.7.1
Copyright (C) 2014 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-linux-gnu".
Type "show configuration" for configuration details.
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>.
Find the GDB manual and other documentation resources online at:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/documentation/>.
For help, type "help".
Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word"...
Reading symbols from exemplo01...done.
(gdb) b main
Breakpoint 1 at 0x40074d: file exemplo01.c, line 50.
(gdb) run
Starting program: /home/ricardobarbosa/dev/c/pilha/exemplo01 

Breakpoint 1, main () at exemplo01.c:50
50              foo(255,255);
(gdb) list
45              c=a+b;
46      }
47
48      double main()
49      {
50              foo(255,255);
51              return 0;
52      }
53
(gdb) s
foo (x=255, y=255) at exemplo01.c:5
5               double a=255;
(gdb) i r $rsp
rsp            0x7fffffffdaf0   0x7fffffffdaf0
(gdb) n
6               double b=255;
(gdb) i r $rsp
rsp            0x7fffffffdaf0   0x7fffffffdaf0
(gdb) n
7               double c=255;
(gdb) i r $rsp
rsp            0x7fffffffdaf0   0x7fffffffdaf0
(gdb) n
8               double d=255;
(gdb) i r $rsp
rsp            0x7fffffffdaf0   0x7fffffffdaf0
(gdb) n
9               double e=255;
(gdb) i r $rsp
rsp            0x7fffffffdaf0   0x7fffffffdaf0
(gdb) n
10              double f=255;
(gdb) 
11              double g=255;
(gdb) i r $rsp
rsp            0x7fffffffdaf0   0x7fffffffdaf0
(gdb) n
12              double h=255;
(gdb) i r $rsp
rsp            0x7fffffffdaf0   0x7fffffffdaf0
(gdb) n
13              double i=255;
(gdb) i r $rsp
rsp            0x7fffffffdaf0   0x7fffffffdaf0
(gdb) n
14              double j=255;
(gdb) i r $rsp
rsp            0x7fffffffdaf0   0x7fffffffdaf0
(gdb) n
15              double k=255;
(gdb) i r $rsp
rsp            0x7fffffffdaf0   0x7fffffffdaf0
(gdb) n
16              double l=255;
(gdb) i r $rsp
rsp            0x7fffffffdaf0   0x7fffffffdaf0
(gdb) n
17              double m=255;
(gdb) i r $rsp
rsp            0x7fffffffdaf0   0x7fffffffdaf0
(gdb) n
18              double o=255;
(gdb) i r $rsp
rsp            0x7fffffffdaf0   0x7fffffffdaf0
(gdb) n
19              double p=255;
(gdb) i r $rsp
rsp            0x7fffffffdaf0   0x7fffffffdaf0
(gdb) n
21              double a1=255;
(gdb) i r $rsp
rsp            0x7fffffffdaf0   0x7fffffffdaf0
(gdb) n
22              double b1=255;
(gdb) i r $rsp
rsp            0x7fffffffdaf0   0x7fffffffdaf0
(gdb) n
23              double c1=255;
(gdb) i r $rsp
rsp            0x7fffffffdaf0   0x7fffffffdaf0
(gdb) n
24              double d1=255;
(gdb) i r $rsp
rsp            0x7fffffffdaf0   0x7fffffffdaf0
(gdb) n
25              double e1=255;
(gdb) i r $rsp
rsp            0x7fffffffdaf0   0x7fffffffdaf0
(gdb) n
26              double f1=255;
(gdb) i r $rsp
rsp            0x7fffffffdaf0   0x7fffffffdaf0
(gdb) n
27              double g1=255;
(gdb) i r $rsp
rsp            0x7fffffffdaf0   0x7fffffffdaf0
(gdb) n
28              double h1=255;
(gdb)
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong? or is my understanding incorrect?
by my studies stack grows as I'm using variables in the function, and the heap would be an area for allocation, am I correct?

Dump the memory

```
(gdb) x/128db $rsp
0x7fffffffdaf0: 0       0       0       0       0       -32     111     64
0x7fffffffdaf8: 0       0       0       0       0       -32     111     64
0x7fffffffdb00: 0       0       0       0       0       -32     111     64
0x7fffffffdb08: 0       0       0       0       0       -32     111     64
0x7fffffffdb10: 0       0       0       0       0       -32     111     64
0x7fffffffdb18: 0       0       0       0       0       -32     111     64
0x7fffffffdb20: 0       0       0       0       0       -32     111     64
0x7fffffffdb28: 0       0       0       0       0       -32     111     64
0x7fffffffdb30: 0       0       0       0       0       -32     111     64
0x7fffffffdb38: 0       0       0       0       0       -32     111     64
0x7fffffffdb40: 46      78      61      -10     0       0       0       0
0x7fffffffdb48: 11      3       64      0       0       0       0       0
0x7fffffffdb50: -1      -1      -1      -1      0       0       0       0
0x7fffffffdb58: -72     -36     -1      -1      -1      127     0       0
0x7fffffffdb60: -8      81      -94     -9      -1      127     0       0
0x7fffffffdb68: -64     116     -1      -9      -1      127     0       0
(gdb) 


(gdb) x/128db $rsp-128
0x7fffffffda70: -56     93      -94     -9      -1      127     0       0
0x7fffffffda78: 0       0       0       0       0       -32     111     64
0x7fffffffda80: 0       0       0       0       0       -32     111     64
0x7fffffffda88: 51      8       0       0       1       0       0       0
0x7fffffffda90: 0       0       0       0       0       -32     111     64
0x7fffffffda98: 0       0       0       0       0       -32     111     64
0x7fffffffdaa0: 0       0       0       0       0       -32     111     64
0x7fffffffdaa8: 0       0       0       0       0       -32     111     64
0x7fffffffdab0: 0       0       0       0       0       -32     111     64
0x7fffffffdab8: 0       0       0       0       0       -32     111     64
0x7fffffffdac0: 0       0       0       0       0       -32     111     64
0x7fffffffdac8: 0       0       0       0       0       -32     111     64
0x7fffffffdad0: 0       0       0       0       0       -32     111     64
0x7fffffffdad8: 0       0       0       0       0       -32     111     64
0x7fffffffdae0: 0       0       0       0       0       -32     111     64
0x7fffffffdae8: 0       0       0       0       0       -32     111     64
(gdb) x/128db $rsp+128
0x7fffffffdb70: -56     -31     -1      -9      -1      127     0       0
0x7fffffffdb78: 0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0
0x7fffffffdb80: 1       0       0       0       0       0       0       0
0x7fffffffdb88: -35     7       64      0       0       0       0       0
0x7fffffffdb90: -64     -37     -1      -1      -1      127     0       0
0x7fffffffdb98: 0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0
0x7fffffffdba0: -112    7       64      0       0       0       0       0
0x7fffffffdba8: -64     -37     -1      -1      -1      127     0       0
0x7fffffffdbb0: 120     7       64      0       0       0       0       0
0x7fffffffdbb8: 0       0       0       0       0       -32     111     64
0x7fffffffdbc0: 0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0
0x7fffffffdbc8: 69      111     -93     -9      -1      127     0       0
0x7fffffffdbd0: 0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0
0x7fffffffdbd8: -88     -36     -1      -1      -1      127     0       0
0x7fffffffdbe0: 0       0       0       0       1       0       0       0
0x7fffffffdbe8: 69      7       64      0       0       0       0       0
(gdb)
```

Comment: You should inspect the assembly code (`-S` option in `gcc`). I think the compiler calculate the stack size before entering in function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do nothing wrong, it's just that `gcc` calculate the stack size at the beginning of the function:

```
void foo(void)
{  
    int a = 0
    int b = 0
    int c = 0;        
}

void bar(void)
{  
    int a = 0
    int b = 0
    int c = 0;        
    int d = 0
    int e = 0
    int f = 0;        
}
```

Will give something like (`gcc -s`, for a i386 CPU):

```
_foo:
    pushl   %esp
    movl    %esp, %ebp
    subl    $12, %esp ; reserve 12 bytes for variables on stack
    movl    $0, -4(%ebp) ; set a
    movl    $0, -8(%ebp) ; set b
    movl    $0, -12(%ebp) ; set c
    leave
    ret

_bar:    
    pushl   %esp
    movl    %esp, %ebp
    subl    $24, %esp ; reserve 24 bytes for variables on stack
    movl    $0, -4(%ebp) ; set a
    movl    $0, -8(%ebp) ; set b
    movl    $0, -12(%ebp) ; set c
    movl    $0, -16(%ebp) ; set d
    movl    $0, -20(%ebp) ; set e
    movl    $0, -24(%ebp) ; set f
    leave
    ret
```

Comment: On the same note, one can view the assembly instructions for a function under gdb by using the disassembly command